# Extending a class in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I got a list of objects like this

```
ArrayList <Page> pageList = aForeignObject.getAllPages();
```

And a child class

```
class MyPage extends Page
{

    public void newFunction()
    {
        // A new Feature
    }
}
```

Is it possible somehow to convert the Page objects into MyPage objects?

I would love to do sth like this:

```
MyPage page = pages.get(1); // This will obviously fail 
page.newFunction();
```

Comment: @C++ Programmers: Is this what we can do with a `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: @Martijn - No, a dynamic cast will only upconvert if the class is of the type (or a subtype) of the class you're converting to.

Answer (score 4):

If the `Page` objects coming out of the `getAllPages()` method are actually `MyPage` objects, then simply use a cast (e.g. `MyPage page = (MyPage) pages.get(1);`. If they're not (as is likely if you're using external code), you can't use sub classes. What you could do, however, is use composition:

```
class MyPage{
    private Page p;

    public MyPage(Page aPage){
        p = aPage;
    }

    public void newFunction(){
        //stuff
    }

    public Object oldFunction(){
        return p.oldFunction();
    }
}
```

Then you could do stuff like:

```
MyPage page = new MyPage(pages.get(1));
page.newFunction();
```

Comment: I thought about this solution however I would have to write 50 "old" functions and have to change it everytime the Page class changes

Comment: How about making it an explicit wrapper then - have a public `Page getOldPage()` method that allows the old methods to be called directly.

Comment: Guess I will do that. Thought there might be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The short solution is casting:</strike>

```
MyPage page = (MyPage)pages.get(1);
```

Note that this requires that the object in question is really of type `MyPage` - otherwise the cast fails with a `ClassCastException`. If you are not sure about it, you may check the type of the object first:

```
Page elem = pages.get(1);
if (elem instanceof MyPage) {
  MyPage page = (MyPage)elem;
  ...
}
```

However, the need to do such downcasts is often a sign that your class design could be improved. If `aForeignObject.getAllPages()` always returns a list of `MyPage` objects, you should change its return type accordingly. Otherwise, if `newFunction` makes sense in the interface of `Page` (even as abstract or with an empty default implementation), you should consider adding it there; then you can call `newFunction` directly on `Page` references without needing to downcast.

**Update:** so you actually have `Page` objects which you want to convert into `MyPage` objects... The technical solution to this would be a *converting constructor*:

```
class MyPage extends Page {
  MyPage(Page other) {
    // deep copy internal state
  }
  ...
}
```

Although technically this is working, I would still rethink the design approach which requires such solutions, if possible. If you use third-party code you can't change, this is not an option though.

Comment: Unfortunately the object is an instance of Page and not of MyPage

Comment: I would love to add the function to Page however it is part of a foreign library. I also don't know how to reach the internal state of the "real" page object.

Comment: @Jan, then I am afraid you have no other choice than the [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) approach proposed by @Scott. As a side note, including all this info in your original post instead of comments would have saved all of us some useless typing...

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously messy but can work...

```
Page page = pages.get(1);
if (page instanceof MyPage) {
  ((MyPage)page).newFunction();
}
```

You can hold a list of all classes that `extends` Page, i.e.

```
List <? extends Page> pageList = aForeignObject.getAllPages(); //Bear in mind that Page objects will never be found here.
```

Now, if the list only contains MyPage, then you can use my example above. Like I said, it's not an effective nor is it an efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to implement your "new feature" in `Page`. I had also a few of these situations before and for me, implementing it in the base class was the solution. But I don't know exactly in what kind of situation your are....

Second solution (not recommend): make your "new feature" a static method. Something like this:

```
public static void feature(Page page)
{
     ....
}
```

Then, you can make a shortcut in MyPage:

```
public void invokeFeatureMethod()
{
     feature(this);
}
```